# Magnetic field due to a straight current wire in 3D

Tags: electromagnetism

How is magnetic field at a point due to current carrying wire calculated in 3D?

Let's say wire has current I placed along x-axis in direction x.

Would it just be $$\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi y} \hat y + \frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi z} \hat z ?$$

I realized that this doesn't quite make sense as when there's a point in $z = 0$, this  would give magnetic field of infinity. How could I get magnetic field in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an infinitely long and infinitely thin wire placed along the $x$ axis, the equation for the magnetic field is $$ \mathbf{B} = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}} \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}_{yz}}, $$
where $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}_{yz}}$ is the azimuthal direction in the $yz$ plane, defined as $\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}_{yz}} = [-\sin(\arctan{\frac{z}{y}}) \hat{\mathbf{x}},\cos(\arctan{\frac{z}{y}}) \hat{\mathbf{y}},0].$

It looks like this:

[image]

and it is translationally invariant along the $x$ axis so any $x$ value would yield the same result. The magnitude of the vectors scale as the distance$^{-1}$ from the origin.

Comment: Harder than it needs to be.

Comment: Really? I thought this was the simplest way, as using Biot-Savart and involving spherical coordinates to derive one seemed nearly impossible.

Comment: Also @SuperCiocia, I would be really greatful if you could show how it was derived using Biot-Savart or other methods.

Comment: you use the standard field from a wire: $\mathbf{B}(r) = \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi r} \hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$ that you get from Ampere's law. In this typical case, you assume the wire is oriented along the $z$ axis, so $r$ is the distance from the $z$ axis in cylindrical coordinates, $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Here I just cast the formula for a wire aligned along the $x$ axis, so my "$r$" is the distance from the $x$ axis which is $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$.